# Getting a parameter from ServletRequest throws illegalStateException

Tags: servlets, jboss, httprequest, httpresponse, servlet-filters

I have this code in one of the filter which is called on every request.

```
httpRequest.getParameter(tabId);
```

My request was failing continuiosly after filters. On debugging I found that this code throws this exception on the first time, now say if I execute this code using "inspect" it throws this exception and if I execute it again using "inspect" or "forward debug" it give "null" and completes the flow. I dont understand why it works like this on first execution of this code as there is not "tabId" in request.

```
18:44:03,443 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/workbench].[action]] (http-0.0.0.0:8090-5) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB002004: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request (128) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.addParameter(Parameters.java:184) [jbossweb-7.5.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:356) [jbossweb-7.5.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:213) [jbossweb-7.5.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2885) [jbossweb-7.5.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1303) [jbossweb-7.5.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:350) [jbossweb-7.5.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.28.Final-redhat-1]
    **at com.xyz.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:58) [projectX.jar:]**
```

Answer (score 0):

The request body has already been consumed, you have to wrap it in your filter (before the `doFilter(...)` call) if you need to do business logic on it. See [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/servlets/httpservletrequestwrapper-example-read-request-body/) for an example.